# Trigger after select

Tags: select, triggers, sqlite

I have a sqlite3-database. There's a table with some logs.
These logs are readed by a tool and were writed to a text-file (or something else) by it.

After this, the logs can be deleted. Is it possible to create a trigger in sqlite3 after a select, which automaticly deletes the logs?

Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_select_x
AFTER SELECT ON x
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM x WHERE id = selected.id;
END;
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such a thing as "Trigger after select". Check out the [Trigger syntax reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

I suggest you use a wrapper function to perform every select statement in your application, and handle the logs in that function.